# how to input symbols through JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i'm using JQuery and aJax with PHP to insert some data to database

but I have a small problem, when i insert data contain (&) symbol .. database read the text before (&) ..

for example .. if the title is ( Sun & Moon ) . it saves it as : (Sun) only .. how can i solve it ?

so this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){  
$('#result').fadeOut("fast");
$('#wait').fadeIn("slow").delay(1000);
    var number = $("input#number").val();
    var title = $("input#title").val();
  var dataAll = 'number='+ number + '&title=' + title ;
  $.ajax({
    url: "../insert/add_module/",
    type : "POST",
    data : dataAll,
    dataType :"html",
    success : function(msg){
        $('#wait').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#result').fadeIn("slow");
         $('#result').html(msg)

    }

  });

});
});
```

Comment: post your php code too..

Comment: problem isn't with php .. i'm using the same functions in another fields but with normal insert, not through aJax , and i get no problem

Comment: try to log the value before inserting into data base and check if its as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var dataAll = 'number='+ number + '&title=' + title ;
```

you could try

```
var dataAll = { number: number, title: title}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the ampersand (&) symbol in URLs otherwise the browser thinks it's the start of another variable pair.

Do a replace of '&' on the title string with '%26' instead.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

&

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper serializing for form data as provided by jQuery [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). The ampersand will be escaped so it doesn't get interpreted as another variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){  
   $('#result').fadeOut("fast");
   $('#wait').fadeIn("slow").delay(1000);

   var dataAll = $('#number, #title').serialize();

   $.ajax({
     url: "../insert/add_module/",
     type : "POST",
     data : dataAll,
     dataType :"html",
     success : function(msg){
         $('#wait').fadeOut("fast");
         $('#result').fadeIn("slow");
         $('#result').html(msg);
    }

  });

});
});
```